# Tate isogeny theorem over varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a nice scheme, $\pi:E\to X$ an elliptic curve, and $\ell$ a prime invertible on $K$. Then we can consider the "Tate module" $(R^1\pi_*\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})^\vee=\hbox{''}\varprojlim\hbox{''} E[\ell^n]$ of $E$, a local system on $X$ of rank two. This gives a stack functor from elliptic curves to local systems, whose domain we can promote to elliptic curves "tensor $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$" (usual caveats about how to correctly define this. By "stack" I mean to include all homomorphisms, not just isomorphisms.)

This stack functor is known to be fully faithful over a finite or number field. This is obviously false over $\mathbb{F}_q[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$, essentially because taking dual numbers doesn't change the étale site to account for the extra elliptic curves. Are there any other cases it is fully faithful, for example (reduced) varieties over finite or number fields?

I come to this question from deformation theory; for other "motivic realizations" we do have facts like this. For example the Serre-Tate theorem along with a theorem of Grothendieck on deformations of p-divisible groups describes how to deform Abelian varieties from characteristic p, and by (a version of) Riemann's theory I think there should be an analogous statement over $\mathbb{C}$ for "sheaves of Hodge structures" (though I remember the correct notion of "sheaf of Hodge structures" being fairly technical.) It would be nice if there were an analogous $\ell$-adic story; though as noted it's not nice enough to do deformation theory for silly reasons, one might hope this works if $X$ has enough points to eliminate these silly reasons.

Comment: Please confer “Moret-Bailly pencils.”  These will have constant Tate module, even though the moduli can vary.

Comment: Now I realize that you only ask whether the Abelian varieties are isogenous.  In Moret-Bailly pencils, all of the Abelian varieties are isogenous (but not isomorphic).

Comment: This is true (at least) for normal schemes  $X$ of finite type over number fields. From a homomorphism of the local systems, you get a homomorphism of abelian varieties over the generic point, hence a (unique) homomorphism over a dense open subset of $X$, which extends uniquely to $X$ by I, 2.7, of Faltings-Chai 1990.